# whole page is redirect after click bootstrap4 tab in angular9?

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular9, bootstrap-tabs

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <nav>
          <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">
                  Project Tab 1
              </a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">
                  Project Tab 2
              </a>
          </div>
      </nav>
      
      ---
      <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
        1st section

        <div>
           <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
        2nd section

        <div>
      </div>
```

Hi Team,
I have add Bootstrap 4 tabs in angular 9 but but problem is that if i click any tab whole page is redirected  instead of tab switch.

I have tried:
 **data-target** insted of **href** but same result.

can anybody tell me how to fix above issue?

Comment: @kiran : can u give me answer for my question?

Comment: what you write in 1 section and 2 section of the tab

Comment: can u make a stackblitz

Comment: i have set only static value but in my case if l click the tab reload whole page